# Unable to hoist custom type to Sanity CMS's top level schema

Tags: sanity

I have been using Sanity CMS for the first time.

I have a schema called article.js that looked like this:

```
import {defineType, defineArrayMember} from 'sanity'


export default {
    name: 'article',
    type: 'document',
      title: 'Article',
      initialValue: () => ({
        publishedAt: new Date().toISOString()
      }),
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'title',
            title: 'Headline',
            type: 'string',
            validation: Rule => Rule.required(),
        },
        {
          name: 'titleJA',
          title: 'Headline (Japanese)',
          type: 'string',
        },
        {
            name: 'mainImage',
            title: 'Main Image',
            type: 'image',
            validation: Rule => Rule.required(),
            options: {
            hotspot: true,
            },
        },
        {
          name: 'bodyHTML',
          title: 'Body HTML',
          type: 'string',
        },
        {
          name: 'bodyHTMLJA',
          title: 'Body HTML (Japanese)',
          type: 'string',
        },
        {
          name: 'body',
          title: 'Article Main Content',
          type: 'array',
          of: [
            defineArrayMember({
              title: 'Block',
              type: 'block',
              // Styles let you set what your user can mark up blocks with. These
              // correspond with HTML tags, but you can set any title or value
              // you want and decide how you want to deal with it where you want to
              // use your content.
              styles: [
                {title: 'Normal', value: 'normal'},
                {title: 'H1', value: 'h1'},
                {title: 'H2', value: 'h2'},
                {title: 'H3', value: 'h3'},
                {title: 'H4', value: 'h4'},
                {title: 'Quote', value: 'blockquote'},
              ],
              lists: [{title: 'Bullet', value: 'bullet'}],
              // Marks let you mark up inline text in the block editor.
              marks: {
                // Decorators usually describe a single property – e.g. a typographic
                // preference or highlighting by editors.
                decorators: [
                  {title: 'Strong', value: 'strong'},
                  {title: 'Emphasis', value: 'em'},
                ],
                // Annotations can be any object structure – e.g. a link or a footnote.
                annotations: [
                  {
                    title: 'URL',
                    name: 'link',
                    type: 'object',
                    fields: [
                      {
                        title: 'URL',
                        name: 'href',
                        type: 'url',
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
            }),
            // You can add additional types here. Note that you can't use
            // primitive types such as 'string' and 'number' in the same array
            // as a block type.
            defineArrayMember({
              type: 'image',
              options: {hotspot: true},
            }),
            defineArrayMember({
              name: 'iframe',
              title: 'Iframe Embed',
              type: 'object',
              fields: [
                {
                  name: 'iframeHtml',
                  title: 'Iframe HTML',
                  type: 'string',
                },
              ],
            }),
            

          ],
        },
        {
          name: 'publishedAt',
          type: 'datetime',
          title: 'Display Date'
        },
        {
          name: 'author',
          title: 'Author',
          type: 'reference',
          to: [{ type: 'staff' }],
        },
        {
          name: 'translator',
          title: 'Translator',
          type: 'reference',
          to: [{ type: 'staff' }],
        },
        {
          name: 'category',
          title: 'Category',
          type: 'reference',
          to: [{ type: 'category' }],
        },
        {
          name: 'feature',
          title: 'Feature',
          type: 'boolean',
        },
        {
          name: 'flickr',
          title: 'Flickr Code',
          type: 'string',
        },
        {
          name: 'slug',
          title: 'Slug',
          type: 'slug',
          options: {
          source: 'title',
          maxLength: 96,
          },
      },
      ]
}
```

All was working fine. However, when I came to deploy a graphQL API, the fact that I was defining the `body` array inline seems to be a problem as documented here: https://www.sanity.io/docs/graphql#33ec7103289a

As such I hoisted the `body` array to a new file called `portable.js` and saved it in the `schemas` folder

```
import {defineType, defineArrayMember} from 'sanity'

export default defineType({
    name: 'portable',
    title: 'Portable Text',
    type: 'array',
    of: [
      defineArrayMember({
        title: 'Block',
        type: 'block',
        // Styles let you set what your user can mark up blocks with. These
        // correspond with HTML tags, but you can set any title or value
        // you want and decide how you want to deal with it where you want to
        // use your content.
        styles: [
          {title: 'Normal', value: 'normal'},
          {title: 'H1', value: 'h1'},
          {title: 'H2', value: 'h2'},
          {title: 'H3', value: 'h3'},
          {title: 'H4', value: 'h4'},
          {title: 'Quote', value: 'blockquote'},
        ],
        lists: [{title: 'Bullet', value: 'bullet'}],
        // Marks let you mark up inline text in the block editor.
        marks: {
          // Decorators usually describe a single property – e.g. a typographic
          // preference or highlighting by editors.
          decorators: [
            {title: 'Strong', value: 'strong'},
            {title: 'Emphasis', value: 'em'},
          ],
          // Annotations can be any object structure – e.g. a link or a footnote.
          annotations: [
            {
              title: 'URL',
              name: 'link',
              type: 'object',
              fields: [
                {
                  title: 'URL',
                  name: 'href',
                  type: 'url',
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      }),
      // You can add additional types here. Note that you can't use
      // primitive types such as 'string' and 'number' in the same array
      // as a block type.
      defineArrayMember({
        type: 'image',
        options: {hotspot: true},
      }),
      defineArrayMember({
        name: 'iframe',
        title: 'Iframe Embed',
        type: 'object',
        fields: [
          {
            name: 'iframeHtml',
            title: 'Iframe HTML',
            type: 'string',
          },
        ],
      }),
      

    ],
  }
)
```

I then updated my `article.js` file like this:

```
import {defineType, defineArrayMember} from 'sanity'
import portable from './portable'


export default {
    name: 'article',
    type: 'document',
      title: 'Article',
      initialValue: () => ({
        publishedAt: new Date().toISOString()
      }),
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'title',
            title: 'Headline',
            type: 'string',
            validation: Rule => Rule.required(),
        },
        {
          name: 'titleJA',
          title: 'Headline (Japanese)',
          type: 'string',
        },
        {
            name: 'mainImage',
            title: 'Main Image',
            type: 'image',
            validation: Rule => Rule.required(),
            options: {
            hotspot: true,
            },
        },
        {
          name: 'bodyHTML',
          title: 'Body HTML',
          type: 'string',
        },
        {
          name: 'bodyHTMLJA',
          title: 'Body HTML (Japanese)',
          type: 'string',
        },
        {
          name: 'portable',
          title: 'Portable',
          type: 'portable',
        },
        {
          name: 'publishedAt',
          type: 'datetime',
          title: 'Display Date'
        },
        {
          name: 'author',
          title: 'Author',
          type: 'reference',
          to: [{ type: 'staff' }],
        },
        {
          name: 'translator',
          title: 'Translator',
          type: 'reference',
          to: [{ type: 'staff' }],
        },
        {
          name: 'category',
          title: 'Category',
          type: 'reference',
          to: [{ type: 'category' }],
        },
        {
          name: 'feature',
          title: 'Feature',
          type: 'boolean',
        },
        {
          name: 'flickr',
          title: 'Flickr Code',
          type: 'string',
        },
        {
          name: 'slug',
          title: 'Slug',
          type: 'slug',
          options: {
          source: 'title',
          maxLength: 96,
          },
      },
      ]
}
```

However even when I restart Sanity CMS, I get the following error:

```
Schema errors
Document type "article"
article:document→fields→[5]:portable Unknown type: portable.

Valid types are: article, staff, category, array, block, boolean, datetime, date, document, email, file, geopoint, image, number, object, reference, crossDatasetReference, slug, string, telephone, text and url
```

This is my first time doing anything in JS/Sanity so probably making some really elementary mistake here; any idea what I am doing wrong?

I have also tried to see if I needed to change my sanity config settings.. but it seems like the schema should be already imported based on the following:

`sanity.config.js`:

```
import {defineConfig} from 'sanity'
import {deskTool} from 'sanity/desk'
import {visionTool} from '@sanity/vision'
import {schemaTypes} from './schemas'

export default defineConfig({
  name: 'default',
  title: '****',

  projectId: '****',
  dataset: '****',

  plugins: [deskTool(), visionTool()],

  schema: {
    types: schemaTypes,
  },
})
```

Thanks for any advice you can give.